# How to get pushed id from recyclerview in datasnapshot?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I need to get the pushed id from firebase while I retrieve all the data from firebase. According to online sources, it said I need to add an ArrayList inside the for loop and set dataSnapshot.getKey().

[image: table]

I need to get the GiLHpCIUXgSleM8a9Bu7uCrwu103.

Main activity.java

```
 ArrayList<String> tkey = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.child("thera").getChildren()){
                    Therapist thera= dataSnapshot1.getValue(Therapist.class);
                     tkey.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    t.add(thera);
                }
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.child("company").getChildren()){
                    Company comp= dataSnapshot1.getValue(Company.class);
                    c.add(comp);
                }

                adapter=new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, t,c,tkey);
                rv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

After that, in the adapter class, i need to pass it to another class by using intent.

Adapter.class

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String clickedItem = String.valueOf(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Thera.class);
                intent.putExtra("tkey", tkey.get(position));
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
```

However, when I try to display the push id from the method I used, it returns a blank. May I know where is the problem of my code? Thanks in advance :)

Thera.class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.therapistdetail);

        String key = getIntent().getStringExtra("tkey");
        setkey(key);

 private void setkey(String key){

        TextView nama = findViewById(R.id.key);
        nama.setText(key);

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `dataSnapshot` instead of `dataSnapshot1`. Use must use `dataSnapshot1` to get the key of the `Therapist` objects

```java
for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.child("thera").getChildren()){
    Therapist thera= dataSnapshot1.getValue(Therapist.class);
    tkey.add(dataSnapshot1.getKey()); // <-- Here you need to use dataSnapshot1
    t.add(thera);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel so sorry that I had made such mistakes